# Do i need to specify all callback URLs in credential page?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

What URLs I need to enter in Google API credential page?
I created an Oauth2 credential for my Google App engine web app.
I entered callback as https://myapp.appspot.com/oauth2callback and it works fine.
Now I am developing V2 and am deploying the app to 2-dot-myapp, Oauth2 stopped working. Do you have to specify callbacks for all versions I am going to deploy?

Comment: No need to specify each callback url for Oauth. I think your url address is changed. Can you please put th error you are getting so i can go through the code

Answer (score 0):

Yep! Google (or any OAuth provider) will not allow people to log in unless the callback URL provided during authorization exactly matches one that configure on the credentials page.